# How can i update order status from checkout with custom payment module?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have payment processing on the **checkout** page on click of place order. 
I get the payment response on the same page. 
Now, I need to update the order status after the checkout form submission in the custom payment module. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

OR

Can I process the checkout form submission in the Controller
`Controller\Index\Index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Create file: `etc/events.xml`

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="sales_order_place_after_event" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SalesOrderPlaceAfter" />
</event>
```

> Create `Vendor/Module/Observer/SalesOrderPlaceAfter.php`

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var Order $order */
    $order = $observer->getData('order');
    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $order->setState('new');
    $order->setStatus('pending');
}
```

Comment: Can I post the additional parameters to this method from the checkout page? such as payment status

Comment: @Garry Yes. You can. But if need only payment info then you can get that from order. $payment = $order->getPayment();